# How to use 'itextESC' when using ex as a text editor in command line?

Tags: shell, command-line, ed, ex

I like using the traditional [`ex`](http://www.csb.yale.edu/userguides/wordprocess/vi-summary.html) editor for simple command line operations, to re-arrange text within files. For example for a simple moving lines across in a file I would use something like

```
foo
bar
zoo
dude
```

to move the text `dude` after `foo` I would just do

```
printf '%s\n' '/dude' 'd' '/foo' '-' 'put' 'wq' | ex file
```

which means move to pattern `dude`, put the line in buffer and paste it after `foo` and `wq` to close the file.

This works fine so far, but I want to insert my custom text to the file, given for example

```
 example
//commented
 abc
 def
```

I need to add another text above `//commented` if pattern `abc` matches i.e. in a file if `abc` is present and above it if a line starting with `//` exists add another line `//new text`, so it should look like

```
 example
//new text
//commented
 abc
 def
```

I tried to do below, using `itextESC` to insert text, but it is not working.

```
printf '%s\n' '/abc' '-' '/\/\/' 'itextESC' 'wq' | ex file
```

I would like to make this work in `ed` or `ex` to explore more about this tool. Would appreciate insights if `ed/ex` can be used for such trivial tasks like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't expect visual commands to work in `ex` mode.  Do use the actual `ex` commands for inserting text, `a`[ppend] and `i`[nsert].

```
printf '%s\n' '/abc' '-' '/\/\/' 'i' 'text' '.' 'wq' | ex file
```

## Further reading

- Dale Dougherty and Tim O'Reilly (1987). "Advanced Editing". *[Unix Text Processing](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/utp/)*. Hayden Books.

Comment: Worked just like charm! It's great that even after 30 years, the old tools just work awesome.